# Unable to access 2d String Array row wise in C#

Tags: c#, datarow

I am taking the data into a 2d string in C#.
Defined as ::

```
string[,] strValueBasic = new string[GridView1.Rows.Count,49];
```

Now i want the data to be taken into DataRows and add these rows into the DataTable.

```
     for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataRow drRow = dtNew.NewRow();
                    drRow.ItemArray = strValueBasic[i];
                    dtNew.Rows.Add(drRow);
                }
```

But i am not able to access this 2d String array in the step

```
                    drRow.ItemArray = strValueBasic[i];
```

It is giving error as Wrong number of indices inside [], expected 2.

I know that it requires 2 indices, but than i want the whole row of that string array to be filled inside that DataRow.

Also the structure of DataRow and String Array is same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign whole row your `strValueBasic` should be defined as `string[][]`. Not the 2D array but array of arrays. That changes initialization too, each array can have different size so you have to create each separately. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thats because `strValueBasic` is a 2D array and you're trying to access it as it's a 1D array.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow drRow = dtNew.NewRow();
                drRow.ItemArray = strValueBasic[i, iSomeOtherValue];
                dtNew.Rows.Add(drRow);
            }
```

Notice **iSomeOtherValue**, you're missing something!

Comment: String [] str = new String[5]{"a","b","c"};
drRow.ItemArray = str;

Hey this works.
So for array or arrays

drRow.ItemArray = strValueBasic[i];

This should also work in a loop.